# subplots_adjust moves axes unpredictably?

Tags: matplotlib, events, subplot

I'm working on a python module that creates a matplotlib figure with an `on_resize` listener. The listener forces the height of the lower axes to a specific number of pixels (rather than scaling relative to figure size). It works. However, if (in matplotlib interactive mode) after creating the plot the user calls `fig.subplots_adjust()` it messes up subplot sizes. Here's a radically simplified version of what the module does:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.ion()

def make_plot():
    fig = plt.figure()
    gs = plt.GridSpec(10, 1, figure=fig)
    ax_upper = fig.add_subplot(gs[:-1])
    ax_lower = fig.add_subplot(gs[-1])
    ax_upper.plot([0, 1])
    ax_lower.plot([0, 1])
    fig.canvas.mpl_connect('resize_event', on_resize)
    return fig


def on_resize(event):
    fig = event.canvas.figure
    # get the current position
    ax_lower_pos = list(fig.axes[1].get_position().bounds)  # L,B,W,H
    # compute desired height in figure-relative coords
    desired_height_px = 40
    xform = fig.transFigure.inverted()
    desired_height_rel = xform.transform([0, desired_height_px])[1]
    # set the new height
    ax_lower_pos[-1] = desired_height_rel
    fig.axes[1].set_position(ax_lower_pos)

    # adjust ax_upper accordingly
    ax_lower_top = fig.axes[1].get_position().extents[-1]   # L,B,R,T
    ax_upper_pos = list(fig.axes[0].get_position().bounds)  # L,B,W,H
    # new bottom
    new_upper_bottom = ax_lower_top + desired_height_rel
    ax_upper_pos[1] = new_upper_bottom
    # new height
    ax_upper_top = fig.axes[0].get_position().extents[-1]   # L,B,R,T
    new_upper_height = ax_upper_top - new_upper_bottom
    ax_upper_pos[-1] = new_upper_height
    # set the new position
    fig.axes[0].set_position(ax_upper_pos)

    fig.canvas.draw()
```

Here's the output if the user calls `fig = make_plot()`:

[image: initial matplotlib figure]

Now if the user calls `fig.subplots_adjust`, the bottom axis is squished and the space between bottom and top axes is even more squished (the `on_resize` listener had set them both to 40px):

```
fig.subplots_adjust(top=0.7)
```

[image: matplotlib figure after subplots_adjust]

At this point, grabbing the corner of the window and dragging even a tiny bit is enough to trigger the `on_resize` listener and restore what I want (fixed pixel height for bottom axes and space between axes) while keeping the newly-added wide top margin intact:

[image: matplotlib figure after manual resize]

**How can I get that result without having to manually trigger a resize event?** As far as I can tell, `subplots_adjust` does not fire off any events that I could listen for.

I *think* the problem lies in [ax.update_params()](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/a78675348aeeb7756014c6d628cd603923f72560/lib/matplotlib/axes/_subplots.py#L126-L131) updating the axes position with a `figbox` taken from the underlying `subplotspec` (which as far as I can tell doesn't get updated after initial figure creation?).  (note: `update_params` is called from within `subplots_adjust`, see [here](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/67c7dca5b385734a3acdad3f84f75f83d5b37ac3/lib/matplotlib/figure.py#L2262)).

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest The callback that calls `set_position` is part of the python module. `subplots_adjust` may or may not be called by the user later (to make room for a title, or to otherwise customize the default figure layout for use in a publication or presentation). As a contributor to the module, I can change how the callback works, but I can't control the user, so if possible I want `subplots_adjust` (which most users know about) to work as they expect it to.

Comment: No, `plt.show` happens in the module, before the user starts interacting with the plot.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I've edited the question and example code to hopefully make it easier for you to reproduce.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198003/discussion-between-drammock-and-importanceofbeingernest).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The underlying problem seems to be to make an axes with a specific height in pixels. An easy solution to this is to use `mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1`'s `make_axes_locatable`.
This allows to get rid of any callback and hence of the complete problem of the race condition in the events.

A note: The plot seems to be part of a bigger library. Since it is always nice not to patronize the users of such packages, one would usually allow them to specify the axes to plot to, such that they can put the plot into a bigger figure with other elements. The below solution makes this particularly easy.

Of course, also calling `plt.subplots_adjust` is still possible at any time.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1.axes_divider import make_axes_locatable

desired_height_px = 40 #pixel

def make_plot(ax=None):
    if not ax:
        fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    else:
        fig = ax.figure
    div = make_axes_locatable(ax)
    cax = div.append_axes("bottom", desired_height_px/fig.dpi, pad=0.25)

    sc1 = ax.scatter([2,1,3], [2,3,1], c=[1,2,3])
    sc2 = cax.scatter([3,2,1],[2,3,1], c=[3,1,2])

    return fig, ax, cax, (sc1, sc2) 


fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1,2)

make_plot(ax=ax1)

#user plot on ax2
ax2.plot([1,3])

fig.subplots_adjust(top=0.7)
plt.show()
```

[image]